# Is there any way to disable - enable WAN miniport with command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, wan

From time to time i need to disable - enable one of my WAN miniports but can't find a way to do it with command prompt/ without going to Device Manager.

Has anyone any idea if that is possible and what would be the syntax?

Comment: Are you open to powershell answers?

Comment: as long as i can execute them in batch files - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD answer at the bottom, The simpler solution worked for me for turning on and off my **WAN Miniport (PPPOE)** obviously change this with the description on your WAN miniport

1. Create a windows shortcut with this Target:

   **Enable:** 
   `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'WAN Miniport (PPPOE)' |Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false"`

   **Disable:** 
   `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName 'WAN Miniport (PPPOE)' |Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false"`
2. In the Shortcut's Properties > Shortcut > Advanced properties, tick
   "**Run as administrator**"

[image]

This bypasses the PS1 file extension forcing you to run this as an admin,

**CMD (Batch File)**

You need to get the reg path for you device '**MSPPOEMINIPORT**' and need to run as an admin

**Enable**

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\MSRRAS\MS_PPPOEMINIPORT /v ConfigFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

**Disable**

```
 reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\MSRRAS\MS_PPPOEMINIPORT /v ConfigFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Comment: It looks like the cmd works but to ask: in my case

`REG_DWORD /d 1` - disabled
`REG_DWORD /d 0` - enabled`

could it be an issue?

Comment: @Ivan69  if it worked please click the tick next to the answer 